# bootstrap-table : passing parameter to $.ajax()

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-table

I am following the example https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/index.html#options/table-ajax.html#view-source

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-height="460"
  data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
  data-search="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-pagination="true">
</table>
```

I would need to pass a parameter in   `data-ajax="ajaxRequest"` let say `switch = 1` to my ajaxRequest script below:

```
function ajaxRequest(params) {        
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "process.php",
           dataType: 'json',
data:{
//I want to pass *switch* variable here to process.php
//how?
} 
           success: function(items) {
                params.success({
                    rows: items

                }, null);
            },
            error: function(er) {
                console.log(params.error(er))
                console.log("error", er);
            }
        })
    }
```

Please help.

-Edit---- 2021/09/29
Thanks @Eitanmg, I read that doc.

So sorry if my question was not clear.

So,
from `view.php` :

```
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-height="460"
  data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
  data-query-params="queryParams"
  data-search="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-pagination="true">
</table>
```

I want to pass `switch = 42` to `ajaxRequest`
so then later in `ajaxRequest` the `data:{ "switch": params.data.switch }`
is processed in `process.php` which contains:

```
if (switch == 42){ 
    task1()
 }else if (switch == 42){
    task2()
 }else { and so on}
```

So the "42" is sent from the `view.php` dinamically. and switch variable will process various function on `process.php` based on the value.

I am looking for advice to send switch parameter from php file to `ajaxRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `data-query-params="queryParams"` to you table as:

```html
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-height="460"
  data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
  data-query-params="queryParams"
  data-search="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-pagination="true">
</table>
```

and add new function with `switch` querystring parameter

```js
  function queryParams(params) {
    params.switch = 42
    return params
  }
```

and in you `ajaxRequest` function you should access it as:

```js
function ajaxRequest(params) {        
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "process.php",
           dataType: 'json',
           data:{ "switch": params.data.switch },
           success: function(items) {
                params.success({
                    rows: items

                }, null);
            },
            error: function(er) {
                console.log(params.error(er))
                console.log("error", er);
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @eitanmg

I modified as follow

in the view,

```
<input type=hidden id=switch value=42>  //     <<<<--- add this
<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-height="460"
  data-ajax="ajaxRequest"
  data-query-params="queryParams"
  data-search="true"
  data-side-pagination="server"
  data-pagination="true">
</table>
```

and catch the variable

```
  function queryParams(params) {
    params.switch = document.getElementById(switch)  //   <<<----------catch like this
    return params
  }

function ajaxRequest(params) {        
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "process.php",
           dataType: 'json',
           data:{ "switch": params.data.switch },
           success: function(items) {
                params.success({
                    rows: items

                }, null);
            },
            error: function(er) {
                console.log(params.error(er))
                console.log("error", er);
            }
        })
    }
```

Then process it in `process.php`

```
if ($_POST('switch')==42) {}
```

However, should you have any smarter method than I coded above please welcome.